# How do I match by two separate arrays of ids in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 arrays with different ids :

1. bikesWithNoOrders [id , id1 , id2]
2. filteredResult [id3 , id5]

How do I make a query that finds them all

I have this :

```js
queryBuilder.find({ _id: { $in: bikesWithNoOrders } });

queryBuilder.find({ _id: { $in: filteredResult } });
```

But the second one overwrites the first one because they dont share the same ids
I want something like this :

```js
queryBuilder.find({ _id: { $in: filteredResult } }).or({ _id: { $in: bikesWithNoOrders } });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just marge these 2 arrays on server side, and query with merged array. You can do it with `concat()`:

```js
queryBuilder.find({ _id: { $in: bikesWithNoOrders.concat(filteredResult) } });
```

Comment: Oh god. Thank you. I guess I should take some rest because I literally didnt even think about that.

Comment: Welcome! Consider also upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer will work for you.!

```
queryBuilder.find({ _id: { $in: [...bikesWithNoOrders,...filteredResult] } });
```